# When to use part/part of versus import/export in Dart?

Tags: dart

I do not completely understand the difference between `part`/`part of` and `import`/`export` when using libraries in Dart.  For example:

```
one.dart:
library one;
part "two.dart";
Class One {
};
```

and

```
two.dart:
part of one;
import 'somefile.dart';
Class Two {
}
```

versus

```
library one;
import 'two.dart';
Class One {
}
```

and

```
library two;
import 'somefile.dart';
export 'somefile.dart';
Class Two {
}
```

Both scenarios seem to do the same thing.  When is it advantageous to use `part` and `part of` rather than `import`? And are there scenarios where `import` will not work, but `part` and `part of` will?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

**update 2018/03**

`part` and `part of` is used more and more for code generation scenarios recently (instead of deprecated transformers) and unlikely to go away anytime soon.

Packages like `built_value`, `json_serializable`, and many others depend on it.

Discouraged is only the patter where all files of a package are tied together to a single library by having one library file and all other files being part of that library.

**original**

In Dart, private members are accessible within the same library.  With `import` you import a library and can access only its public members. With `part`/`part of` you can split one library into several files and private members are accessible for all code within these files.

*see clarifications to below paragraph in above update*

Using `part` / `part of` is discouraged and the Dart team is considering getting rid of it. I assume they will introduce something like "friend" (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/22841), where two libraries can access each other's private members as an alternative before they discontinue `part` / `part of` (maybe in a future Dart version).

Comment: It's 2020, and they have kept part/part of. What do you think about the future?

Comment: There is an issue about supporting partial classes where I got the impression the Dart team plans to implement in the foreseeable future. That might depend on `part`. Otherwise, it's still useful for how code generation is used. Also the way private works in Dart it might be useful in some situations where a file grows too big, but couldn't otherwise be split because then code in one file couldn't access private stuff in the other files. With `part` it's easy to split anyway. Not a very common case though as far as I am aware of.

Comment: 2021 and part/part of still there, stronger than ever. I don't see the point of the team to tell us to avoid using it if they don't induce changes in a timely manner. If they want to make radical changes it would definitely break a lot of Flutter apps and packages.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL the Dart team (as in many other such projects) sometimes do a poor job in telling WHY something should be avoided when they say it should. `part` `part of` was very commonly used to treat the whole project as a single library with everything part of some `lib/my_package.dart`. And I think this is what they refer to when they discourage using `part`/`part of`. Their own code generator packages **require** `part` `part of`, so it's safe to assume that you are not doing anything wrong when you use it in such situations.

Comment: 2023 and these features are still part of Dart language core. Perhaps, it's come to stay.

Comment: 2024 and these functionalities continue to be integral components of the Dart language core. It appears they are here to stay.

Answer (score 41):

Let's suppose we have a Dart *library* called `mylib`, whose file is `lib/mylib.dart`.

```
library mylib;

// Definitions
```

That library can be included in the `main.dart` file as

```
import 'package:mypackage/mylib.dart';
```

---

When you create a new library and use other libraries you want to make available automatically when using your package, then you use `export`:

```
library mylib;

export 'otherlib.dart';

// Definitions
```

You can use the `show` keyword to import/export only some parts of a library (like a class or something).

---

You are using the `part of` directive wrong here. You can't use both `library` and `part of`, which is used to specify the contents that belong to a library. For example, you can split your library file in more than one file (the parts):

Suppose we have in the file `mylib.dart`:

```
library mylib;

part 'src/class1.part';
// More parts
```

And then we have in another file `src/class1.part` the part specified in `mylib.dart`

```
part of mylib;

class Class1 { 
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  The use of part of and library was just a typo, so I edited it out for future readability of the question.

Comment: @Robert I have a dilema between **importing** your own files (say a file with a class definition, services, etc) vs making them **part of** your library. I find that using `import` makes it pretty clear what the dependencies of each files are, but then you have keep adding imports every time you use something new, while `part/part of` just give you everything but then you don't know the dependencies. Also, your main library file then has all the dependencies. Then one thing I appreciate is creating top level function on the main library file. What do you think?

Comment: You can do it as you want :)

Comment: @Robert But there is a difference: All parts of a library have access to private members while shielding them from anything outside the library. In that sense they work more or less like `Go` packages or (this is a stretch) like splitted classes in C#. If you have a file with private and public members and only want the public ones to be exported then `part of ` can be useful. Or if you really really need to shield some private members from the outer world. But most of the time the "don't touch `src`" convention solves that problem and is just good enough.

Answer (score 24):

using `part/part of` makes many files be treated as if they were one file

`import/export` doesn't, so this may be useful when private fields need to be accessed from another files (classes created on other files)

Comment: The simpler the better "makes many files be treated as if they were one file".
I got it, thank you (I didn't with all the other answers)

Answer (score 19):

The [Creating Library Packages](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/create-library-packages.html) article on the dartlang.org site recommends avoiding `part` / `part of`.

> Note: You may have heard of the part directive, which allows you to
>   split a library into multiple Dart files. We recommend that you avoid
>   using part and create mini libraries instead.

The 'mini libraries' referred to are small library dart files in `src` which are imported into and exported from main libraries.