# Inherited Classes aren't able to use main class methods if in different files in Dart

Tags: class, flutter, dart

I have this Foo class:

```
class Foo {
String s;
  Foo(){
    _update();
  }
  void _update() {
    s = "t";
  }

}
```

And this Foo2 Class.

```
class Foo2 extends Foo {
  String s;
  Foo2();
  void _update() {
    s = "t";
  }

}
```

In the same .dart file. If I create a Foo2 object and print its s variable, I will get that the variable has a value of "t". But if I move the Foo2 class to another .dart file and import the first, Android studio won't see the _update method as used and when creating a Foo2 object and printing its s value I get null.

Why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Identifiers with a leading `_` are *private* to that Dart library.  Normally that means private to that file, although there's a ([not well-documented](https://github.com/dart-lang/site-www/issues/1263)) [`part` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763378/when-to-use-part-part-of-versus-import-export-in-dart) that can be used if you want to split a library across multiple files.

Comment: Not seeing `_update` in `Foo2` as being used is because of it being private, as @jamesdlin pointed out. However, the other behavior you described doesn't seem to be accurate -- in my testing it still prints a value of `t` for `s` even when the classes are in separate files.

Comment: Thank you! That solved it!! Just a question? Should I keep this answer or delete it as it's an error that I made?