# Should subclasses inherit private mixin variables in Dart?

Tags: dart, mixins

Should I get the following error:

> class.dart:11:11: Error: The getter '_privateID' isn't defined for the class 'Y'.
>       - 'Y' is from 'class.dart'.
>      Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '_privateID'.

From the following code?

**mixin.dart**:

```dart
class Mixin {
  static int _nextID = 0;

  int publicID = _nextID++; // I only need one of these lines
  int _privateID = _nextID++; // but this variable is inaccessible
}
```

**class.dart**:

```dart
import 'mixin.dart';

class X with Mixin {
  void run() {
    print(publicID); // no error here
  }
}

class Y with Mixin {
  void run() {
    print(_privateID); // Error: _privateID not defined
  }
}

void main() {
  Y().run();
}
```

Or is this a bug? If it's not a bug, I'd like to understand why this behavior is reasonable.

When I instead define the mixin in the same file as the above classes, I get no error.

(Dart SDK 2.4.1.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a bug.
The private field is *inherited*, but you cannot access it because its name is private to a different library.

Dart's notion of "privacy" is *library private names*.
The name `_privateID` in the `mixin.dart` library introduces a library private name. This name is special in that it can *only* be written inside the same library.
If someone writes `_privateID` in a different library, it is a *different name*, one unique to that library instead.

It is as if private names includes the library URI of the library it is written in, so what you really declare is a name `_privateID@mixin.dart`.
When you try to read that field in `class.dart`, you write `._privateID`, but because it is in a different library, what you really write is `._privateID@class.dart`, a completely different name, and the classs does not have any declarations with *that* name.

So, if one class needs to access a private member of another class (or mixin, or anything), then the two needs to be declared in the same library, because otherwise they cannot even *write* the name of that variable.

That is why the code works if you write the mixin in the same library.
If you want to move the mixin to a separate file, but not necessarily a separate library, you can use a [`part` file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763378/when-to-use-part-part-of-versus-import-export-in-dart).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! Experimenting further now, I see that I also can't access `_private` upon extending `Mixin` treating it as a class. I should have tried that before posting here. I assume each file is its own library unless otherwise extended, regardless of the locations of the files? Most explanations out there assume you know what a "library" is before telling you how to package them. I guess I'm still thinking in terms of Java or Kotlin.

Comment: Almost all Dart files are individual libraries. Only libraries can have `imports`. The exception is *part* files which are not libraries themselves, but are merely included in a library in another file. You include a part in a library with a `part "partfile.dart";` declaration, and mark the part file as being one by starting it with a `part of "thelibrary.dart";` declaration pointing to the library it is a part of. The Dart *language* currently does not have any other granularity for code organization than libraries, although tools may be aware of Pub packages.