# How to access private fields without the 'part of' directive?

Tags: dart

Set the case there are multiple libraries of a package which need access to a commonly used class which is in its own library. This class gets exported and contains private fields which should only be accessible internally by libraries of the package. Because the `part of` directive is discouraged I am avoiding it. So this is the challenge: How can I access private fields of a public class from another library of the same package without using `part of`?

This is what a came up with:

```
class PublicClass {
  Object _shouldNotBePublic;
}

class InternalClass extends PublicClass {
  Object get publicInternally => _shouldNotBePublic;
}
```

And it partially solves the problem.
But now there is an exported function

```
void someFunction(PublicClass param) {
  param._shouldNotBePublic;
}
```

which takes an argument of `PublicClass` and it needs to access the private `_shouldNotBePublic` field. That is exactly what C++ `friend` does. Are there any good solutions for Dart that don't involve `part of`?

**Edit:** The workaround I use for the time being is a simple not exported function in the same library like `PublicClass`:

```
Object getShouldNotBePublic(PublicClass obj) {
  return obj._shouldNotBePublic
}
```

Comment: Not really much of an answer but have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763378/when-to-use-part-part-of-versus-import-export-in-dart

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot. As you already figured out, you have to export explicitly. Of course, if you have to export it, why make it private is another question.

Comment: @TomYeh because it shouldn't be visible to the users of the library.

Comment: Instead of exporting the class directly, you perhaps could split the class into an exported base class and a non-exported derived class.

Comment: @jamesdlin Well, that is exactly what I did.