# how to use part or part of in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, import

Can anyone give an example of using part and part of?

I have 2 simple dart file and I want to use private or public argument from a file to another using part or part of, But it is not possible

like below:

a.dart: int _a = 5;

b.dart: part 'a.dart' (or part of 'a.dart') can't access to _a!!!

Comment: See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763378/when-to-use-part-part-of-versus-import-export-in-dart)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use part/part of versus import/export in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763378/when-to-use-part-part-of-versus-import-export-in-dart)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You must declare parts in the file that other files are part of.

`file_a.dart`

```dart
part 'file_b.dart';

const _myPrivateValue = 'myPrivateValue';
```

`file_b.dart`

```dart
part of 'file_a.dart';

void usePrivateValue() => print(_myPrivateValue);
```