# Is there a reason not to use part and part of instead of import in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know when to use `part` and `part of` in pure dart, but I haven't found any information about using it in a flutter app (for Widget for example) instead of import, so I'm curious if there is a reason that in that case.

Consider an example where you have a page with a tab bar. To improve maintainability you create the pages in separate files.

Now there are two options: `import` the pages or make them `part of` the tab bar page. The latter has the advantage that the pages can be private classes, and you can have private classes in the tab bar page if there are components that are shared between the pages.

To me this seems like a good solution, but since I haven't found anyone that has done it this way I'm starting to think that there might be some drawbacks. Is there a reason to use `import` instead of `part` and `part of` in this case?

`tab_bar_demo.dart`

```dart
part 'page1.dart';
part 'page2.dart';
part 'page3.dart';
part 'page4.dart';

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(
            children: [
              _Page1(),
              _Page2(),
              _Page3(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PageContentWrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

`page1.dart`:

```dart
part of 'tab_bar_demo.dart';

class _Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to use part/part of versus import/export in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27763378/when-to-use-part-part-of-versus-import-export-in-dart)

Comment: That question is about pure dart, my question is about using it a flutter app and if there is a reason no one seems to use it in that regard

Comment: I'm sorry for not responding your question. I see some use of the part in the package mobx, the generated class is called using it on the writen class, as you can see in their examples here: https://mobx.netlify.app/concepts