# Can I use library keyword in personal project but not in library

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `Flutter`. As you are aware, Flutter `doesn't have protected` keyword to make classes package private. But interestingly, the same could be achieved using `library`, `part`, `part of` keywords once I name widgets starting with underscore. But, I am a bit worried about `performance issues`.

Question: Is it ok to use `library/part/part` of keywords inside `ordinary projects`?

Answer (score 1):

public classes inside `lib/src` are considered package private. Only classes in `lib` are truly public, so are files in `lib/src` when they get exported by a file in `lib`.

```
enchilada/
  lib/
    enchilada.dart <-- public
    src/
      beans.dart <-- package private unless exported
```

While technically you can access everything in `lib/src`, you get a warning when you use [implementation files](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout#implementation-files).

[image: Warning: Don't import implementation files from another package.]

### Don't use part

The `part` keyword can not be used to hide code, it inherits the same visibility as the library. All it does is splitting a file into multiple files. It should only be used for code generation these days https://stackoverflow.com/a/27764138/669294

> Note: You may have heard of the part directive, which allows you to split a library into multiple Dart files. We recommend that you avoid using part and create mini libraries instead.

[source](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#organizing-a-library-package)

### Performance

Visibility doesn't affect performance in any way.

Comment: yes but I am naming widgets with underscore which is making them private for the lib

Comment: The underscore means "file private" in dart. You can only use the class in that file. If you want to access it somewhere else in you package make it public. If you're not exporting it, it's not public for the outside world

Comment: But, my intention is to show the file only within its package to neighbouring files but not outside. If I make it public, it will be visible to everyone

Comment: I need this because, I have many similar-named widgets in the project so I need to hide them inside their own package

Comment: You can't show files to only "neighboring" files in dart, as you can in Java with package private classes. Instead, you could extract a package.

Comment: what do you mean by extracting?

Comment: Create a new package and move the source code there

Comment: Thank you for your response)

Answer (score 0):

Naming your entity starting with an underscore (for example `_test`) should make it private.

> Libraries not only provide APIs, but are a unit of privacy: identifiers that start with an underscore (_) are visible only inside the library. Every Dart app is a library, even if it doesn’t use a library directive.

<sup>[Source](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#libraries-and-visibility)</sup>

Comment: I think It makes it private for the file

Comment: @KhamidjonKhamidov No it's actually the library, I added the relevant quote.

Comment: doesn't it affect performance when I use the library keyword? I am doing as you suggest but I am worried about performance issues. When I import the mini library in another class, doesn't it impact performance?