# Flutter build web exclude specific folder from minify

Tags: flutter

I am looking for some help in `flutter build web`. When I run this command, it minify the code and create a build folder to deploy `web` app. There are few models which I don't need to **minify**. How can I **exclude** model folder?

I am using Flutter **3.3.10** and Dart **2.18.6**

Comment: i don't know your usecase but there is no specific way to exclude some models but in profile mode minification is not perfromed.

https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/web#minification

Comment: I am using **Hive Db**. There is one generic method i.e., `OpenBox`. Which check box is already open or not. So, I am using` T.toString()`  and this cause an issue after minification.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, In your build.yaml file, set `enableMinification`: to true. It will enable minification for the web target. Then you can add `exclude`: list after that and add the model folder directory to it. Something like this,

```
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      build_web_compilers|entrypoint:
        enabled: true
        options:
          compiler:
            enableMinification: true
            exclude:
              - "models/**"
```

Comment: I think this answer is not complete. Is there anything missing above `options:`?

Comment: Edited the answer. Thought the provided answer was enough to figure it out. Try now.

Comment: This doesn't work. My `models` folder is in `lib` folder

Comment: Then use "lib/models". You have to customize according to your directory path.

Comment: I tried like "lib/models/**". but doesn't work.

Comment: ** were for you to edit your own path in this sample code. Don't use it as it is. If you wanna exclude the whole models folder, use "lib/models" in your case

Comment: I thought ** means, it will take all files. Let me try it.

Comment: To build I am running these command. 1: `flutter clean` 2: `flutter pub get` 3: `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs`

Comment: Is this a correct way?

Comment: Tried this **lib/models** but didn't work.

Comment: Looks correct. Just make sure you don't have the `build` directory available when you are executing this. and once you clean build the project, invalidate cache and restart the IDE just in case. Only then run the `flutter build web`. And it seems like  "lib/models/**" is the correct line if you want to exclude sub directories in the models folder.

Comment: I have tried it but it doesn't work. I have tried this type of config also. Please check this https://github.com/dart-lang/build/blob/master/build_web_compilers/build.yaml

Comment: Can you add the error you're getting. cause this generally works buddy. Otherwise you will have to use `part` Directive of dart to create separate libraries. It can keep the models folder separately from the rest of the project. here is how/when to use [part](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27763900/14577209)

Comment: There is no any error. When I run the web app in release mode it will show **minified** class name in console.